# Modeling relations efficiently in a no-SQL database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I'm struggling with how to model one-to-many and many-to-many relations in a NoSQL database like Firestore.
I want to model Teachers, Pupils, and Classes: a Pupil is part of at least one class, a Teacher can teach multiple classes.
In a relation database, this would probably result in the following tables (I'm no database expert at all)

- Class (id, name)
- Teacher (id, name, phone, email)
- Pupil (id, name)
- class2teacher (classId, teacherId)
- class2pupil (classId, pupilId)

I want to be able to do the following queries:

- for a given Class, which Pupils are in it
- for a given Teacher, which Classes does he/she teach
- for a given Class, which Teachers teach it

But what is the idiomatic way to model this in NoSQL, eg Firestore?  I've read that joins are not available in NoSQL and that data duplication is not uncommon in NoSQL but I'm confused as to how the database structure would look like.

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. Please edit your question and show us what those queries are.

Comment: In the relational model & logic (& engineering & science & CS & math) an n-ary relation(ship)/association is represented by a n-column (base or view or query result) table. Follow a published information modelling & DB design textbook/reference method & find relevant base relations. Then follow the official Firestore manual & references re design--to find the queries (using bases) to store in Firestore. Research is required for SO questions so you should do that anyway before you post here. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck/unsure. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy  I agree it is a beginners question and a pretty generic question.  I tend to learn faster when I can start from a simple example from my application domain.  But the generic pointers/background you provided are certainly also useful.

Comment: You're still asking us to rewrite textbooks & manuals plus a bespoke tutorial, you need to read & follow them etc per my last comment & finally ask re being 1st stuck/unsure. This sort of question is too broad--though nevertheless also a faq. There's no foundation on which to give or justify an answer. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we intend to perform, for the following queries:

1. for a given Class, which Pupils are in it
2. for a given Teacher, which Classes does he/she teach
3. for a given Class, which Teachers teach it

Please check the following schema:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- classes (collection)
  |     |
  |     --- $classId (document)
  |           |
  |           --- id: "classId"
  |           |
  |           --- name: "ClassName"
  |           |
  |           --- pupils (array)
  |                |
  |                --- 0: "pupilId"
  |                |
  |                --- 1: "pupilId"
  |
  --- teachers (collection)
  |     |
  |     --- $teacherId (document)
  |           |
  |           --- id: "classId"
  |           |
  |           --- name: "TeacherName"
  |           |
  |           --- phone: "+000..."
  |           |
  |           --- email: "email@gmail.com"
  |           |
  |           --- classes (array)
  |                |
  |                --- 0: "classId"
  |                |
  |                --- 1: "classId"
  |
  --- pupils (collection)
        |
        --- $pupilId (document)
              |
              --- id: "pupilId"
              |
              --- name: "PupilName"
              |
              --- teachers (array)
                   |
                   --- 0: "teacherId"
                   |
                   --- 1: "teacherId"
```

I'll write the queries in Java, but it simply can be translated into other programming languages too.

Considering the following rootRef:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

And the following collection references:

```
CollectionReference classesRef = rootRef.collection("classes");
CollectionReference teachersRef = rootRef.collection("teachers");
CollectionReference pupilsRef = rootRef.collection("pupils");
```

#1. To get the pupils that exist in a class, you have to create a reference to that particular class:

```
DocumentReference classIdRef = classesRef.document(classId);
classIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

Download the document, and get all pupil IDs that exist in the "pupils" array. Then for each pupil ID, create a new reference:

```
DocumentReference pupilIdRef = classesRef.document(pupilId);
```

And get their corresponding data.

#2. In the same way, we did above, do it also in the case of teachers. Get the classes from the array and create a separate database call for each class to get the corresponding data.

#3. Same as before.